# How to add multiple queries to flutter_socket_io to connect to a socket?

Tags: flutter, socket.io

To connect to my socket, I need to pass token and an userType along with the connection endpoint. Please check below for the socket implementatin:

```
  socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
          query: {
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyQWNjZXNzIjoiMjYwLWI5MDNjN2I3LThmYmUtNDc3Yi04OTEzLTJkYmRiNmQ3YWFmMiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMzYyNjU1MSwiZXhwIjo4NjQwMDAwMDAxNjEzNjI2MDAwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMzAifQ.zlY5IQUZ0Hb91xmCCRuHJ-md4RO37-1bbmQCn_Oi_R4",
            userType: "1",
          }
        });
```

I am using flutter_socket_io package to connect my flutter app to a socket. I am using the following code:

```
socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO('https://someUrl', '/', query: 'token:$tok, userType:1', socketStatusCallback: _socketStatus);
```

The above gives me undefined variables as the token and usertype passed in the query is not passed correctly. According to flutter_socket_io documentation I have to send query like this:

```
socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO("http://127.0.0.1:3000", "/", query: "userId=21031", socketStatusCallback: _socketStatus);
```

I would like to know how can i send two variables in query parameter of flutter_socket_io package.

Comment: Can you try this one : 
socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO('https://someUrl', '/', query: 'token=$tok?userType=1', socketStatusCallback: _socketStatus);

Comment: I used & instead of ? and it worked. Thanks anyways